# IEC 60320 C13/C14 Voltage Rating

Tags: voltage

According to the standard, C13/C14 plugs don't have a set voltage (unlike something like a L6-20P), so it is up to the consumer/manufacturer to decide which voltages are appropriate.

I recently stumbled upon a C13/C14 cable that had "10A 125V~" imprinted on the C13/C14 connectors. The cable itself was rated for 300V and was 18AWG.

My question is, what exactly determines the voltage rating (in this case 125V) for the connector portion of the cable? Would it be considered "safe" to use this in a 208V circuit (many C13/C14 cables are commonly used in datacenters to supply 208V).

Comment: here I see cables rated with two voltages what does it say on your cable.

Comment: sorry, could you clarify? In my case, it has "10A 125V~" printed on the connector portion (not the cable). The cable itself has "300V" on it and is 18awg.

Comment: cables here say 300v/500v

Answer (score 2):

The isolation defines the voltage-hardness of any connector.

Basically, I wouldn't know how to build a C13 plug that was only safe for 125V; the pin distances definitely are large enough, and if you attach the conductors at the position of these pins, then these contacts are far enough from each other, too.

But I'm not in the business of making cheap connectors.

However, the most likely explanation for a "125 V" marking on that cable is that it comes from a supplier that targets a 120V market. Often, names matching what the customer expects outweigh technical specification in marketing.

(that's the reason why you can get "Samsung USB cables" on ebay, that are not built by Samsung at all. People have a phone and want to buy a cable. They type in the only text on that phone into ebay. Same goes for power cables. People live in a country with 120 V. They don't want to stand in an aisle and hold a cable that's rated for 240 V; that just confuses them.)